# Which is faster and less resource intensive? Using more rows in MySQL or using substr from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, performance, substr

Which is less resource intensive and faster?

Scenario 1:

Storing in MySQL in 10 columns INT values

Scenario 2:
Storing the the Int values in only one column and using substr() from PHP to get the individual INT value for further processing?

Comment: storing multiple values in a single field negates the primary purpose of a relational database. as for speed, you'd have to benchmark your particular setup.

Comment: Which has more meaning to whoever has to maintain code that you write? There's an infamous psychopath who knows where you live who'll be hunting you down in six months time if you use scenario #2

Comment: Yeah, putting data in strings like this defeats the whole purpose of using a database. If you want to do it like this then you can just as well throw it in a text file (that is essentially what the database will become, if you do this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy to answer:

Use the `INT` columns...

1 `INT` column costs 4 bytes, and can store values from -2147483648 to 2147483647 (note: 10 digits)

4 bytes in a `VARCHAR` column (assuming that's what you're referring to) only stores 4 digits (or less depending on the encoding you used)

If you don't want to use 4 bytes for an INT, you can use a different type. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

As for speed... The difference will be negligible, and it would only be premature optimization. (also I think the `substr` method you are suggesting would always be slower, the cost of `substr` is O(N), whereas a table lookup with proper indexing is O(log N), regardless of # of columns)

My own preference will always be on the side of flexibility, therefore use the individual `INT` columns, you never know if you want to sort/filter by/aggregate each individual column.

Answer (score 0):

Not the direct answer to your question, but the best way to test for execution speed:

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);

// YOUR CODE TO BENCHMARK HERE

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Took $time seconds\n";
```